# C# Regex.Split, How do I split string into surrounded by parenthesis and not surrounded by parenthesis?

Tags: c#, regex, parentheses

Given the string `"I'm not surrounded by parenthesis (but I am) so what."`, how would I use regex to split it into a `string[]` that looks like this:
`[0] = "I'm not surrounded by parenthesis "`
`[1] = "(but I am)"`
`[2] = " so what."`

Alternatively, Is there a way to replace `(but I am)` with the same string but surrounded by a tag? Say for example `[b](but I am)[/b]`.

I've tried using the Regex.Replace method with `\(([^\)]+)\)` as the regular expression. But I need a replacement string in the method's parameters. Given that the replacement string should be whatever matches the RegEx, I don't quite know how to execute this method.

Comment: You can [edit] the question instead of adding information in a comment. And yes, that's definitely possible, but have you tried something first? We'd like to see you do an attempt before asking - you usually learn more that way.

Comment: Well by the time I post here it's because I can't come up with an answer myself. I did try to research, but can't find the proper technique to do it. A friendly nudge in the right direction would be nice... but if that is not possible I will keep on trying.

Comment: I wasn't looking for you to answer it yourself, but just to explain what you had tried before asking. I see you added exactly that to the question now, which is great. That gives us something to work with and makes it easier to give an answer so you can more easily see what you missed or where you went wrong.

Comment: I see I'll be more specific next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, [this](https://regex101.com/r/OhgKCS/1) should give you what you wish:

```
(\([^)]+?\)|[^(]+)
```

Just make sure you use `Regex.Matches`, not `Regex.Match`, since it will return a match for each parentheses and non-parentheses groups.

For your second question, a simple call like this should do it:

```
string s = ...;
Regex.Replace(s, @"\([^)]+?\)", @"[b]$1[/b]");
```

Comment: So just to clarify. The `$1` is a "Substitution in a Regular Expression"  right?

Comment: It substitutes the first capture, yeah